# I can't get my nested for loop to engage

Tags: java, arrays, loops, nested, duplicates

I'm trying to write a program that takes an array of integers, scans for and removes any duplicate values and then returns the remaining values as an ArrayList.

I feel like I am on the right track as far as how to do it but I can't seem to get the necessary nested for loop to engage. Here is my code so far.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Justin
 */
public class ArrayOps4 {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int [] cake = {2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3};
        System.out.println(copyArray(cake));
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param anArray
     * @return
     */
    public static ArrayList copyArray(int [] anArray) {
        // your work here

        // declare the new ArrayList
        ArrayList<Integer> nal = new ArrayList<>();
        // loop through anArray, eliminating duplicates,
        int [] Array2;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < anArray.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 1 ; j < anArray.length ; j++)
                if (anArray[j] == anArray[i]) {
                    for (int m = j ; m < anArray.length ; m++) {
                        anArray[m] = anArray[m++];
                    }
                }
        }

        for (int ii = 0 ; ii < anArray.length ; ii++) {
            nal.add(anArray[ii]);
        }

        // storing each unique element in the ArrayList

        // your work here

        // return new ArrayList
        return nal;
        // your work here
    }
}
```

Everything else seems to work fine but the second for loop which is supposed to rotate through all of the integers in the array and compare them to the position being held by the first for loop won't engage. When I debug it in Netbeans the variable for the first for loop just increments itself and then moves onto the ArrayList creation loop which works great.

I would greatly appreciate any input around what I am doing wrong, or if this program is even going to do what I think it will once it's working.

**After taking into account the helpful advice from everyone i'm closer but i'm still stuck. My revised code is still having trouble with two strings of input and I just can't figure out why**

```
package arrayops4;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Justin
 */
public class ArrayOps4 {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int [] cake = {2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 6, 11};
        System.out.println(copyArray(cake));
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param anArray
     * @return
     */
    public static ArrayList copyArray(int [] anArray) {
        // your work here

        // declare the new ArrayList
        ArrayList<Integer> nal = new ArrayList<>();
        // loop through anArray, eliminating duplicates,
        int counter = 0;
        int length = anArray.length;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < anArray.length ; i++) {
            for (int b = i + 1 ; b < anArray.length ; b++) {

                if (anArray[i] == anArray[b]) {

                    for (int ii = b ; ii < anArray.length - 1 ; ii++) {
                        anArray[ii] = anArray[ii + 1];

                    }
                    counter++;
                }

            }

        }
        length = length - counter;
        for (int k = 0 ; k < anArray.length - 1 ; k++) {
            nal.add(anArray[k]);
        }
        return nal;
    }
}
```

**The inputs that are still giving me trouble are [2, 14, 9, 15, 9, 7, 3, 17, 14] and [3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5]. The first set returns [2, 14, 9, 15, 7, 3] and is missing the 17. The second set returns empty brackets. Any further help would really be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.  **

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `anArray[m] = anArray[m++]; `? (a)You're messing with the `for` variable, `m`, with `m++`, and (b)it's basically only incrementing m since assignment occurs first, then incrementation. So the array can't change and m counts by 2. Are you sure you don't want something like `anArray[m] = anArray[m + 1]`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

```
for(int j=1;j<anArray.length;j++)
```

should initialize `j` to `i+1` in order to start with the next element, and the code that removes elements should also decrease the effective length of the array (since decreasing the actual one is not possible). You need to add an `int` variable `effectiveLength`, initialize it to `anArray.length` initially, and decrement by one each time that you remove an element from `anArray`.

Consider changing your algorithm in favor of a less intrusive and faster one that builds the result as it goes:

- For each element of `anArray`, check if it is present in `nal`
- In order to do that, loops through all elements of `nal`, and compare it to `anArray[i]`
- If you did not find the match, add `anArray[i]` to `nal`
- Continue to the next element.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I would much rather just loop through the array list checking for duplicates but it's a homework problem and it specifically says to remove the duplicates from the array before converting to an arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great application for set theory.
The Iterator class makes it easy to iterate through a collection and remove elements.

```
Integer[] cake= {2,3,4,3,2,4,5,4,6,6,6,4,3};
List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Collections.addAll(array, cake);
HashSet<Integer> hash = new HashSet<Integer>();
Iterator<Integer> iter = array.iterator();

while(iter.hasNext())
{
    Integer val = iter.next();
    if (hash.contains(val))
    {
        iter.remove();
    }
    else
    {
        hash.add(val);
    }
}
System.out.println(array);
```

Comment: Actually if you don't care about the order of the returned numbers, then it's even easier...  Add them all to a HashSet and return the HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

You are using postincrement:

```
           anArray[m] = anArray[m++];
```

This will not do what you intended, but copy the value to the same index it already resides in. Furthermore you are incrementing m twice, as the for statement already does this.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think you really want to change the contents of anArray. Wasn't the idea to leave it intact and just have the copy be free of duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the gist of it. You were in the ballpark. Major spacing is to draw attention to alterations to your code.

```
   for(int i=0;i<anArray.length;i++)
   {
       for(int j=    i+1      ;j<anArray.length;j++)
       if(anArray[j] == anArray[i])
       {
        for(int m=j;m<anArray.length      - 1      ;m++)
        {
         anArray[m] = anArray[m      +1      ];   
        }
       }
   }
```

But you also have to keep track of how many times you shifted the entire array toward [0] for your printout loop to print ONLY what remains after the shifts. Otherwise output is 2,3,4,5,6 [and this should be the end],6,3,3,3,3,3,...